# Netsh set rule depends on OS language

Tags: windows, powershell, networking, cmd

I was creating a batch script to run several commands to enable winrm, changing network category and such and I got across a problem with the netsh command, specifically `netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group=”Network Discovery” new enable=yes`

After digging around and messing with UAC and registry I understood my problem: Windows language.

So the command is setting the rule to the `Network Discovery`, however in my language (portuguese btw) the group is called `Deteção de Rede` and thus making the script unable to run across several Windows machines with different languages, making the user enable network sharing manually.

My question is: Is there global way of calling the `Network Discovery` group? or creating a new group linking to it?

This is my script btw:

```
@ECHO ON
REM Run as admin
powershell.exe /c Get-NetConnectionProfile;
powershell.exe /c Set-NetConnectionProfile -NetworkCategory Private;
powershell.exe /c netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group=”Deteção de Rede” new enable=yes
cmd.exe /c winrm quickconfig -q
cmd.exe /c winrm set winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true"}
cmd.exe /c winrm set winrm/config/service/auth @{Basic="true"}

@ECHO Done.
```

Comment: Is there another command that will list the groups? What does `netsh firewall dump` produce on your machine?

Comment: It produces nothing. I'm now trying to produce a cycle to output and save the LCID as a variable to use it in a if condition and use a command with the group in the right language

Comment: This might be helpful. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc749376(v=ws.10)

Comment: Also, this. https://superuser.com/questions/1115639/how-to-activate-file-and-printer-sharing-on-a-french-windows-system-from-command

Comment: Thanks for that last link. Now I just need to find the append for the `FirewallAPI` to enable the network sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thankfully to @lit I found a way to set the rules to the group.
Used the command `powershell.exe /c netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="@FirewallAPI.dll,-32752" new enable=Yes` to enable Network Sharing and `powershell.exe /c netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="@FirewallAPI.dll,-28502" new enable=Yes`to enable files and print sharing
(if you want to use this to target a windows machine you may want to activate them both) and now i'm able to run my ansible playbook to windows